# How to automate change log and release creation

Tags: github-actions

I want GitHub Action to create a Change Log and Release Tag when a pull request is merged to the master branch.The current code I have below seems to be creating a version tag out of order and not creating a release.

```
name: Changelog & Releases
on:
 push:
   branches:
     - master

- name: Changelog Action
        id: changelog
        uses: TriPSs/conventional-changelog-action@v3
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 

      - name: create release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        if: ${{ steps.changelog.outputs.skipped == 'false'}}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ steps.changelog.outputs.tag }}
          release_name: ${{ steps.changelog.outputs.tag }}
          body: ${{ steps.changelog.outputs.clean_changelog }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working Github Actions workflow that I use with one of my release pipelines.

This is exactly the same as your use case. So feel free to use it.

The release action that you are using is currently unmaintained, so use the one that I've mentioned in the workflow below.

```yaml
name: Release using conventional commits (master branch)

on:
  push:
   branches:
     - master

jobs:
  release:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest

   steps:
    - name: checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: conventional changelog action
      id: changelog
      # https://github.com/TriPSs/conventional-changelog-action
      uses: TriPSs/conventional-changelog-action@latest
      with:
        # you can also create separate token to trace action
        github-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"

    - name: create release
      # https://github.com/actions/create-release
      uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
      if: ${{steps.changelog.outputs.skipped == 'false'}}
      env:
        # This token is provided by Actions, you do not need to create your own token
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
          tag_name: ${{ steps.changelog.outputs.tag }}
          name: ${{ steps.changelog.outputs.tag }}
          body: ${{steps.changelog.outputs.clean_changelog}}
          draft: false
          prerelease: false
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response.do i need to have package.json at the root of my directory for this to work?

Comment: no. what does the package.json contain?

Comment: the package.json is empty

Comment: no you wouldn't need it. try it without the package.json and let me know

Comment: thanks,i will let you know in few mins

Comment: still creating change log out of order and not generating release

Comment: release
Tried to read "/home/runner/work/changelog-test/changelog-test/package.json" but file does not exist!

Comment: The version could not be detected, using fallback version '0.1.0'.

Comment: those are the messages im getting

Comment: ok, create a package.json with a "version" key, and place it at the root of the repo. example ` "version": "1.5.1",`

Comment: @ Tharun,the code is not even creating Changelog.md at the root of the repository and not generating any release

Comment: @bibi would be better if you share the logs

Comment: ,I created a new repo to test with the code you suggested,changelog and release tag was created.However the same code did not generate changelog and release tag in my other repo with 240commits in it.is it possible that the 240 previous commit could be the issue?

Comment: The logs will provide you the answer. So go through them. As you said that my code worked. Can you accept the solution?

Comment: ,setting skip-on-empty : false   did the trick. once again thanks